# How to log Mono call results?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to create a controller that call multiple API :

```
FIRST CALL

IF SUCCESS
    CALL ANOTHER FIRST API
    CALL ANOTHER SECOND API
ELSE
    RETURN API ERROR
```

To do that, i use spring-cloud-gateway. I didn’t find any functionality to do this with spring cloud so I realized this via a spring controller.

So i have created a class with a method to call my first API :

```
public Mono<ProUserResponse> createProUser(UserCreationRequest request) {
            Function<UriBuilder, URI> uri = uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                    .path(userProperties.getCreateProUser().privateEndpoint())
                    .build();
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create();
                httpClient.wiretap("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient", LogLevel.DEBUG, 
            ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
    
    
            return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(clientHttpConnector).baseUrl(userProperties.getCreateProUser().baseUrl().toString()).build().post()
                            .uri(uri)
                            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .bodyValue(request)
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(ProUserResponse.class)
                            .retry(3);
        }
```

I have also created a controller :

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<MerchantCreationResponse>> createNewMerchant(@Valid @RequestBody MerchantCreationRequest merchantCreationRequest) throws MerchantCreationException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    // Create User
    Mono<ProUserResponse> user = monolitheHttpClient.createProUser(merchantCreationRequest.merchant()).log(log.getName());

    final AtomicReference<MerchantCreationResponse> response = null;
    //Long userId = user.toFuture().get().userid();
    user.doOnSuccess(proUserResponse -> {
        log.info("youpi");
        System.out.println("This is a message");
    }).doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Failed for some reason", throwable));

     return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

When i call my controller, the request returns me an Http 200 code but i have no log on the success or on the error.

How can i display my query result ? Is it the good approach ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't execute the that mono, i.e., there is no subscription to it.
Your `user` Mono kept untouched.

You just create an object that could be called, never call it, and then return always 200 response that doesn't take into account any real work.

The code should look like:

```
return user.map(result -> {
    new ResponseEntity(result, HttpStatus.OK)
});
```

Which means *subscribe to user mono and then provide with the following result*.

You may also want to handle errors and other situations, like:

```
return user
    .map(result -> {
        new ResponseEntity(result, HttpStatus.OK)
    })
    .onErrorResume(t -> {
        new ResponseEntity(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_ERROR)
    })
    .switchIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

Comment: Thanks Igor for your response. Is it possible to call multiple API call into this map ?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on how you want to call multiple APIs. Here you want just one result (and one HTTP response), so the `map` should receive one input. So you probably want to merge them before. You can use a `zip` for example, like `callOne.zip(callTwo).map {...}`

Comment: In fact it’s not that simple. callOne return me an id to call callTwo.

Comment: In that case you can use a `flatMap` like `callOne.flatMap(id -> executeCallTwo(id)).map {}`

Answer (score 0):

You need a subscriber to user [Mono](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) and add chain of actions using [map](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) for success response, and on error you can use [onErrorResume](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorResume-java.util.function.Function-) to return `ResponseEntity` with appropriate status code

```
return user.map(data -> {
          //log the data if needed
          return new ResponseEntity(data, HttpStatus.OK)
          }).onErrorResume(throwable -> {
                 log.error("Failed for some reason", throwable));
                 return new ResponseEntity(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
               });
```